# Can I have multiple leftOverlay items in UITextField or 2 independent texts at the same time?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I've been a long time lurker and want to start with a huge thanks to everyone. Now,

My main problem is that my client wants to show user selected tag's like in the image below

[image: textfield with user selected tags]

can I add multiple small views in a leftOverlay and if that's not possible can I add the selected tag word like a static text/placeholder and let the new search text start right where it ends ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be implemented using `UICollectionView` and custom flowlayout. This can help you [custom flowlayout](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)